# Weak Net Convergence and Approximate Identities

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading through the text "Complete Normed Algebras" by J.J. Bonsall and J. Duncan.

Let $ A $ be a normed algebra.

**Definition:** A **weak left approximate identity** for $ A $ is a net $ \{ e(\lambda) \}_{\lambda \in \Lambda} $ such that $ f(e(\lambda)x) \to f(x) $ for every $ x \in X $ and for every $ f \in X^* $.

**Proposition 2 (p.58):**  Let $ A $ contain a bounded set $ U $ such that, given $ x \in A $, $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists $ u \in U $ with $ \| x - ux \| < \epsilon $.  Then $ A $ has a bounded left approximate identity.

**Proposition 4 (p. 59):** If $ A $ has a bounded weak left approximate identity then $ A $ has a bounded left approximate identity.

*Proof:* Let $ \{ e(\lambda) \}_{\lambda \in \Lambda} $ be a weak left approximate identity for $ A $ and let $ U $ be the convex hull of $ \{ e(\lambda) : \lambda \in \Lambda \} $.  Since $ e(\lambda)x \to x $ in the weak topology on $ A $ there exists $ u \in U $ such that $ \| x - ux \| < \epsilon $.  Apply Proposition 2.

**My question:**

1. To apply proposition 2 I need to verify that the set $ U $ in proposition 4 is bounded.  Since $ \{ e(\lambda) \}_{\lambda \in \Lambda} $ is a bounded left-approximate identity this means that there exists an $ M > 0 $ such that $ \| e(\lambda) \| \leq M $ for every $ \lambda \in \Lambda $.  If $ U $ is the convex hull of $ \{ e(\lambda) : \lambda \in \Lambda $ then why is it true that $ U $ is bounded?  My idea is, let $ u \in U $.  Then $ u $ is a finite convex combination of points in $ \{ e(\lambda) : \lambda \in \Lambda \} $ so there exists $ \lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n \in \Lambda $ and $ 0 \leq \alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n \leq 1 $ with $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_k = 1 $ such that $ u = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_k e(\lambda_k) $.  So $ \| u \| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_k \| e(\lambda_k) \| \leq M $.  Is this correct?
2. Why does there exist a $ u \in U $ such that $ \| x - ux \| < \epsilon $?  What property of convergence in the weak topology is being used here?  I am not familiar with the weak topology in regards to nets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $1$ you are correct.  Another way to observe this to recall that the convex hull of a set is the intersection of all convex supersets.  Since the ball $B$ of radius $M$ at $0$ contains $\{ e(\lambda) : \lambda \in \Lambda \}$ and is convex, $B$ also contains its convex hull, namely $U$.

For $2$, $x$ is in the weak closure of $\{e(\lambda)x:\lambda\in\Lambda\}$, hence is in the weak closure of its convex hull.  But for convex sets the weak closure and norm closure coincide, so we have $x$ in the norm closure of $Ux=\{ux:u\in U\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the great response!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!